# Asp.Net Core RTM StaticFileMiddleware: how to pass IOptions<StaticFileOptions>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

In my team we're migrating an ASP.NET Core RC1 web app to RTM. There's a custom middleware that internally creates an instance of `StaticFileMiddleware`. In RC1 it used to be:

```c#
// ctor signature:
StaticFileMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv,
  StaticFileOptions options, // <--
  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory);
```

and we could easily create and pass an instance of `StaticFileOptions`. Now in RTM is:

```csharp
// ctor signature:
StaticFileMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv,
  IOptions<StaticFileOptions> options, // <--
  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory);
```

and I have no idea on how to create an `IOptions<StaticFileOptions>`. Actually I have no idea how to create an `IOptions<T>` in general, having a `T` instance around.

[Latest reference](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/StaticFiles/StaticFileMiddleware/) doc page, not yet on top Google results, does not provide any hint. And search results on `StaticFileMiddleware` are quite scarce in general.

Anyone knows how to proceed? This is actually preventing us to move forward with migration. TA

Comment: take a look at `options pattern` docs https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects

Comment: thanks for comment. I'm aware of that, we already `Configure<Topt>` options taken from sections from built `IConfiguration` settings, and then inject `IOptions<Topt>` in other parts. In current scenario we create a `StaticFileOptions` inside some method, depending on logic & values at runtime, and in same method we need to pass that to middleware c'tor. So now should we split this in two, a part where we build and register option instance with DI, and another part where we inject and use that instance?

Comment: Why don't you use something like this?   `services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>{
           // your logic
           options.DefaultContentType = "<content-type>";
           // set other options
  });` Isn't it enough for your case?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. I still have to try that at runtime, but at least on paper it should work. To your reply: I find it somehow strange having to register & inject a dependency on a single concrete instance, only to grab it and pass it to a constructor. And this is all strictly tied together, all pertinent to one method body. Don't like that such an instance should be around available as a dependency for the whole app. I know it's the way they're passing options to middlewares now, but if I can avoid that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like static `Options` class in `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` namespace provides a `IOptions<TOptions> Create<TOptions>(TOptions options)` static factory method. Did not run yet, but at least it does not fail the build.

BTW looking at Asp.Net Core [Options github issues](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues) and PRs there's a whole host of discussion that went on around Feb/Mar (2016) about this usage pattern. Just to name a few: [Is#122](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/122), [PR#757](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/pull/757), [PR#719](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/719), [PR#124](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/pull/124). [Issue #105](https://github.com/aspnet/Options/issues/105) led me in the (hopefully) right direction.